# python web3 interaction with smart contract

Tags: python, smartcontracts, web3py

I'm using web3.py to transact a smart contract method. Though broadcasted successfully, etherscan thinks its an "eth" transfer and not a smart contract interaction.

The method intended is mint(). 
Please find my code below:

```
infura_url = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<Infura code here>"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
address = w3.toChecksumAddress(<My wallet address>)
abi = json.loads(<ABI here>)
contract=w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

mint_tx = contract.functions.mint(address,1).buildTransaction()
mint_tx['nonce'] = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(mint_tx, private_key=os.environ['private_key'])
txhash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(f'Transaction hash: {txhash.hex()}')
```

It should be like below (Done on etherscan manually):
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xf6626aa3bbfeb67f3798ad1145ec89c8995b0db9315e88cbf9b915f4610b8872

But as of now it's like below (From python):
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x6b43cebf69b82bcbf8cce654a24627688b4fe9ea7d43dd74b4fa4c1c1049a3c7

Am I missing a step before sending the transaction ?
Any help is greatly appreciated. If any more information is required, do let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong address for your contract. Notice the `To:` and `Interacted With (To):` fields on etherscan.

You have

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
```

where `address` is your *wallet* address.

You should have

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)
```

where `contract_address = '0xeB74D88306e09A78570795d7467F729ffA786651'` in your case.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and help. It now gives "account is the zero address" error, but that's another issue so I'll go ahead and look into it. Very much appreciated , have a nice day ! (Or night, depending on where you are).